# spring boot camel 3 camel-endpointdsl vs uri strings non compatibility because of double slash //

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

We are migrating from camel `2.x` to camel `3.x`

I am transforming routes written using uri strings from these routes definition formats

```
//xml routes
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:inputqueue?disableReplyTo=true" />
    <to uri="direct:loadConfiguration" />
</route>


//java routes
from("direct:loadConfiguration"))
.bean(myBean, "loadAllConfiguration(${body})");
```

to endpoint-dsl format below:

```
from(activemq("loadConfiguration").disableReplyTo(true))
.to(direct("loadConfiguration"));

from(direct("loadConfiguration"))
.bean(myBean, "loadAllConfiguration(${body})");
```

The thing is, the URI formats register the routes like so:

```
org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Route: route4 started and consuming from: activemq://queue:inputqueue?disableReplyTo=true
org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Route: route5 started and consuming from: direct://loadConfiguration
```

But the new camel dsl format registers the routes like so (without //):

```
org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Route: route4 started and consuming from: activemq:queue:inputqueue?disableReplyTo=true
org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Route: route5 started and consuming from: direct:loadConfiguration
```

The problem is routes that get registered with double slash appended to component (URI behavior) are not matched with the routes registered without the double slash (new endpoint-dsl behavior).

And I have to transform all the routes to either use URIs OR endpoint-dsl. Otherwise I get errors on messages telling there is no consumers for route `direct://loadConfiguration` for example... because `from(direct("loadConfiguration"))` is defined using the dsl and it's registered as `direct:loadConfiguration`.

Is there a configuration option to make camel not append `//` to components when using URIs or to make camel ignore its `//` ?

Comment: What Camel version do you use? I think we have fixed this in latest release or the next.

Comment: I am using `org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.2.0` and `org.apache.camel:camel-endpointdsl:3.2.0` @clausIbsen

Comment: Yeah wait for Camel 3.3.0 release, or use regular route builder without endpoint-dsl until then